# Discord.js - Bot wont stop spamming the embeds (Instead of asking the user to react)

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently in the process of making a little fighting 1-on-1 bot, where it asks each player whether he'd like to attack or protect.

Attacking deals a random damage between 5-40, and Protect reduces the maximum amount of damage you could take.

Currently, when running the bot, it seems to be spamming the embeds I've created for asking what move the player would like to make using reactions, and it doesn't really seem to stop in order to actually ask for the user's input.

Any chance someone could help?
Thanks!

( Full code: https://sourceb.in/ikOVzF8B0w )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## let's clean up that code

ok. first thing that caught me out was the long `possibleHealth1` and `possibleHealth2` arrays. replace this with a nice inline like this

```js
Array(36).fill(null).map((_,i) => i + 5)
```

or wrap this in a function

```js
function range(length, start) {
  Array(length).fill(null).map((_,i) => i + start)
}
```

and run it as

```js
range(36, 5)
```

another problem is that you need to call one thing after another quite often, you are using `Promise.prototype.then` here but you should use [async/await syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

finally, get some bloody semicolons in there (no offence)

## the actual issue

a while loop is the best choice here, keep going until one player depletes their all their opponents hp.
we need a side variable to keep track of which player is going right now

```js
const possibleHealth = Array(36).fill(null).map((_,i) => i + 90);
let j = 0;
let d = 0;
const author = message.author.id;
const member = message.mentions.users.first();
const memberName = member.username;
let Player1Health = 100;
let Player2Health = 100;
let side = 0;
if (member === undefined) {
  return message.channel.send('Incorrect Syntax. Please mention a user! (!fight {user})'); // Do not proceed, there is no user.
}
while (Player1Health > 0 && Player2Health > 0) {
    if(side === 0) side = 1;
    else side = 0;
}
```

this will loop indefinitely flipping side each loop
the next step is to add a slightly modified async/await version of your function to the loop

```js
const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${side === 0 ? message.author.username : memberName}'s turn!`)
    .setDescription('What would you like to do?\n⚔️ Fight!\n️ Protect!\n❌ End Game')
    .setColor(3426654);
const sent = await message.channel.send(Embed)
await sent.react('⚔️');
await sent.react('️');
await sent.react('❌');
const filter2 = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['⚔️', '️', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === author;
}
const collected = await sent.awaitReactions(filter2, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time']
});
const reaction = collected.first();
if (reaction.emoji.name === '⚔️') {
    if(side === 0) {
        Player2Health -= possibleHealth[Math.floor(possibleHealth.length * Math.random())];
        sent.channel.send(Player2Health);
    } else {
        Player1Health -= possibleHealth[Math.floor(possibleHealth.length * Math.random())];
        sent.channel.send(Player1Health);
    }
} else if (reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
    if(side === 0) {
        j = 10;
    } else {
        d = 10;
    }
} else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
    return sent.channel.send('Game ended.')
}
```

this is by no means a finished game, just one that doesn't have your problem. your opponent can play for you and i have no clue what those `j` and `d` variables do, but at least it works as a primitive 1v1

one last thing i would recommend is replacing the async/await reactions

```js
await sent.react('⚔️');
await sent.react('️');
await sent.react('❌');
```

with a [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
await Promise.all([sent.react('⚔️'), sent.react('️'), sent.react('❌')]);
```

all of these reactions will happen at the same time